# calling another scripts to run in current script

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm writing a shell script. what it does is it will create a file by the input that is received from the user. Now, i want to add the feature called "view a file" for my current script. Now, it's unreasonal to retype it again since i've already had a script that helps

I know it's crazy when it is possible to it with normal shell command. I'm actually writing a script that help me to create pages that are generated from the touch command. (this pages had attached date, author name, subjects, and title).

The question is how to call a another script or inhere another script?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ways to do this. My prefered way is by using `source`
  You can -

- Call your other script with the source command (alias is .) like this: source /path/to/script.
- Make the other script executable, add the #!/bin/bash line at the top, and the path where the file is to the $PATH environment variable. Then you can call it as a normal command.
- Use the bash command to execute it: /bin/bash /path/to/script

Comment: The second way sounds really  ergonomic and something is more intuitive in programming. Thanks a lot